# How to get cell id starting from row 1 and on using jQuery

Tags: jquery, vb.net, .net-4.0

I have a generic table that has every id in every cell. I am able to obtain id of a cell I click on however I need to only get ID from cells starting from row 1 and so on ... The table I have does not have header row it is a plain generic table but the very first row I need to just IGNORE when I click in there. My code so far:

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    alert("ID" + $(this).find('a').attr('id'));
    // ... continue code
    });
});
```

also in every cell i have

```
<span class="trigger"> ... my code inside of a cell(s) goes here ... </span>
```

This is an example of  looks like:

```
<td class="inboxTableCell">
    <span class="trigger">
        <a id="1" href="#">New Email</a>
    </span>
</td>
```

This is all dynamic and I am generating id(s) on the fly and able to display id for this particular cell.

My problem is when I click on the title or the very first row in a table it must not get the id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to alert the ID of the `a` except if it's the first row.

This should do it. Check if the index of the parent `tr` is greater than 0, then do the alert etc..

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    if($(this).closest('tr').index() > 0){
        alert("ID" + $(this).find('a').attr('id'));
        // ... continue code
        });
    }
});
```